# Left join event table to incident table where dates are closest for each device id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table as follows:

`T1`

```
event_id device_id event_time  var1 var2
1        A         2021-01-01  5    6
2        C         2021-01-02  8    7
3        B         2021-01-05  1    6
4        C         2021-01-07  7    7
5        D         2021-01-12  8    9
6        C         2021-01-18  3    4
7        B         2021-01-21  7    1
```

`T2`

```
device_id incident_time
B         2021-01-06
C         2021-01-17
```

I would like the Output to be

```
device_id incident_time event_id event_time var1 var2
B         2021-01-06    3        2021-01-05  1    6
C         2021-01-17    6        2021-01-18  3    4
```

So, I am trying to find `event_id`, `event_time`, `var1` and `var2` of a single event in `T1` where the event time is closest to the `incident_time` for each device in `T2`, irrespective of if `event_time` is bigger or smaller than `incident_time`. My ugly (and incorrect) code so far:

```
 select T2.device_id, T2.incident_time, (select distinct on (device_id) event_id 
                                         from T1
                                         where device_id = T2.device_id 
                                         and event_time <= T2.incident_time
                                         order by device_id, event_time desc) as event_id
 from T2;
```

How can I accomplish this more elegantly using Join statement? Or is the select as statement in brackets correct? How can I include all the required columns? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that two events could be appropriate for the same incident_time of a particular device?

Comment: For example, if table T1 had one more row like this: 8 B 2021-01-07 <any value> <any value>.

Comment: Yes, possible for T1 to have multiple rows for any device. The actual T1 is a few hundred million rows big, and T2 is a few thousands, which makes a left join take very long. I can't only use the top 1 entry for each device_id because of multiple entries of the same device_id in T2. Busy looking at your approach below. I will appreciate if you could amend your answer below for this.

Comment: I used "With Ties" in my approach, so "Fetch First 1 Rows" does not just extract the first event with the closest event_time to the incident_time for a particular device, but also all events that have the same absolute minimum difference between their event_time and the incident_time, so I think my solution meets your requirements.

Comment: I also changed "Cross Join Lateral" to "Left Join Lateral" in my query to select rows from table T2 that do not match any row in table T1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "Fetch First 1 Rows With Ties" via "Left Join Lateral" to get all suitable events for each incident.

```
Select T2.device_id, T2.incident_time, T1.event_id, T1.event_time, T1.var1, T1.var2
From T2 Left Join Lateral
(Select T1.event_id, T1.device_id, T1.event_time, T1.var1, T1.var2
 From T1 
 Where T1.device_id=T2.device_id
 Order by Abs(T1.event_time-T2.incident_time)
 Fetch First 1 Rows With Ties) As T1 On true
```

Comment: Nice, just remember that it's the derived table which is _lateral_, not the join.

Answer (score 3):

Skip the subquery, do a join instead. Something like:

```
select distinct on (T2.device_id) T2.device_id, T2.incident_time,
                                  T1.event_id, T1.event_time, T1.var1, T1.var2
from T2
left join T1 ON T1.device_id = T2.device_id 
order by T2.device_id, ABS(T2.incident_time - T1.event_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table T1(event_id int, device_id varchar(2), event_time date,  var1 int, var2 int);
 insert into T1 values(1        ,'A'         ,'2021-01-01',  5,    6);
 insert into T1 values(2        ,'C'         ,'2021-01-02',  8,    7);
 insert into T1 values(3        ,'B'         ,'2021-01-05',  1,    6);
 insert into T1 values(4        ,'C'         ,'2021-01-07',  7,    7);
 insert into T1 values(5        ,'D'         ,'2021-01-12',  8,    9);
 insert into T1 values(6        ,'C'         ,'2021-01-18',  3,    4);
 insert into T1 values(7        ,'B'         ,'2021-01-21',  7,    1);
 
 create table T2 (device_id varchar(2), incident_time date);
 insert into T2 values('B',         '2021-01-06');
 insert into T2 values('C',         '2021-01-17');
```

Query 1 (using cte and row_number() window function):

```
 with cte as
 (
   select T2.device_id, T2.incident_time,T1.event_id,T1.event_time,T1.var1, T1.var2,
   row_number()over(partition by T2.device_id order by ABS(T2.incident_time-T1.event_time))rn
   from T2 left join T1 on T2.device_id=T1.device_id
 )
 select device_id, incident_time, event_id, event_time, var1, var2 from cte
 where rn=1
```

Output:

| device_id | incident_time | event_id | event_time | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2021-01-06 | 3 | 2021-01-05 | 1 | 6 |
| C | 2021-01-17 | 6 | 2021-01-18 | 3 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f2589e6919832fd5ca6592f7de78d079)*

Comment: Your distinct on query is 100% the same as mine, which was the first answer to this question. Just a coincidence?

Comment: @jarlh thanks for notification. I have removed the second query. Best wishes.